# SleepConditionVariableCS equivalent ON XP

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi

I am implementing some functions using `SleepConditionVariableCS`, `WakeConditionVariable` and `WakeAllConditionVariable`. 
But these APIs are not supported on windows XP.

```
Wait()
{
   SleepConditionVariableCS(&mCondition, &myCriticalSection, INFINITE);
}

WakeSingleThread()
{
    WakeConditionVariable(&mCondition);
}  

WakeAllThreads()
{
    WakeAllConditionVariable(&mCondition);
}
```

I am wondering how to write equivalent code on XP.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look to see if you can perform the equivalent tasks with one of the [many wait functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687069%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) available on XP platforms.

I'm not completely familiar with those Windows-specific condition variable functions, but I'd bet you can perform similar tasks with WaitForObject.  You'd need to monitor the condition yourself and call SetEvent() to signal the waiting code to wake up.

Before I switched to C++ 11 thread and synchronization primitives, I had a wrapper class that encapsulated basic wait-and-signal functionality.  It shouldn't be too much more work to add the mechanism to evaluate a condition and signal based on it, although I think you're going to have to spin on the condition.  I'm not sure I know a way around that.

Comment: If you don't know how to answer in detail, you don't need to answer. This "answer" says, in essence, "you can do this, if you just work it out for yourself". That's not really the kind of answer we are looking for here.